# PHP / Replace non latin characters with its counterparts

Tags: php, replace, str-replace

**WORD**

```
AŠA
```

**PHP**

```
<?php

foreach (glob("*.jpg") as $filename) {
    $search = array("Š");
    $replace = array("S");

    $newname = str_replace($search, $replace, $filename);
    echo $filename.'<br>'.$newname;

    //($filename, realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/'.$newname);
}
```

**PROBLEM**
It does not replace character "Š" in word "AŠA"

Comment: Its working...!!! http://codepad.org/kpM4S68O

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [iconv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) which allows you to convert a string to a specified encoding.

Example for your case:

```
$str = 'AŠA';
$str = iconv('UTF-8', 'ASCII//TRANSLIT', $str); // ASA
```

Answer (score 9):

The previous method does not work having latin characters such as ü or áéíóú it returns 'a'e'i'o'u instead aeiou.

What about `transliterator_transliterate`. Works for PHP >= 5.4

```
$str = 'AŠAáéíóú';    
transliterator_transliterate('Any-Latin; Latin-ASCII;', $str); //ASAaeiou
```

[Reference PHP NET: transliterator_transliterate](http://php.net/manual/en/transliterator.transliterate.php)

Comment: When I repeatedly use transliterator it fails randomly every so often... Gives a Maximum execution time of 120 seconds exceeded.

Comment: @JasonEngage the error might be due to another process in your script, it slould not take that long. Working example: [link](https://www.tehplayground.com/KHuBnhLTd3i2XznO)

Comment: The php error points to 

$transliterator = Transliterator::createFromRules(':: Any-Latin; :: Latin-ASCII; :: NFD; :: [:Nonspacing Mark:] Remove; :: Lower(); :: NFC;', Transliterator::FORWARD);

It only happens 1 in 10,000 times, but it causes a fatal error. I'll wrap in a Try however it may not catch it...

Comment: @JasonEngage by the number of iterations sounds more like you are running out of memory or maybe an execution timeout rather than an isolated error. Try increasing the `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time` on your php.ini or reducing the load of your script with less iterations.